# How can I get both tf and tf2 working in ROS

Tags: ros, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(geometry/tf)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package angles.

Set angles_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
angles.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
anglesConfig.cmake
angles-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
geometry/tf/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- tf: 1 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tf_conversions'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(geometry/tf_conversions)
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:~/catkin_ws$ sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-tf
No candidate version found for ros-hydro-tf

I have a working version on BBB where I see both tf and tf2* in /opt/ros/hydro/share.  I have a non working version with no tf in share.  how do I build or install tf so it either get's to share or is built in a catkin workspace?  I have geometry built in the carkin workspace - and it list tf as being there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191730/how-can-i-get-both-tf-and-tf2-working-in-ros/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-02**:
As of hydro tf uses tf2 under the hood. There should be no conflict between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cmake error you posed indicates that you don't have the angles package installed. Have you tried installing it?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-angles
```

More generally, if you have a workspace where the dependencies may be missing, you can usually install them with rosdep:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaanoguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/55284/kaanoguzhan/) on 2020-05-27**:
Thank you !!
I wish your more general option would be mentioned on more places !

I guess even in 6 years this important info is still missing from many places